# Function implementation in matlab

Tags: matlab, implementation

I want to implement this function [, ] = (^( +)*u[]  using 41*41 array, where u[n] =1 since all the value will be positive ,and n,m from 0 to 40, But it gives wrong value.

```
N=40
a=0.9
x =zeros(41,41)
for k=0:N
  for col = 1:41
    for row = 1:41
        x(row,col)=a.^(k+k)*1;
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Any help,please

Comment: What is it returning and what are you expectig?

Comment: What is the meaning of `k‘ in your code? It doesn’t appear in the equation.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the k loop and your indices are off by one.

```
N=41;
a=0.9;
u=1;
for m=1:N
  for n=1:N
    x(n,m)=a^(n-1+m-1)*u;
  end
end
```

If you want to actually declare it as a function, you could delete the first three lines in the above code and then wrap it as below. Be sure to save the function to its own file in your working directory where the file name matches the function name.

```
function x=filename(a,N,u)
%Above code here.
end
```